# Clear Content before running a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to simply clear a range D4:F17 before running and onEdit function that inputs data.

The range will clear and then the function runs. The original numbers, that were supposed to be cleared, pop back up and ruin the new data.

I understand this is most likely due to the fact that both functions will try to run almost simultaneously, so I tried different combos of the below code, from what I've read in other posts, in the middle of the function and in its own function. Doesn't seem to work and have the same problems mentioned above.

```
range.clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
Utilities.sleep(10000)
```

Comment: About `both functions will try to run almost simultaneously`, can you provide more information? For example, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue by including your script? I think that it will help users think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, when the simple trigger and the installable trigger are used, those work with the asynchronous Processing. Please be careful this. https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5

Comment: If you have the function that does the calculations, why not clear the values from that function, at the beginning of it, to avoid conflicting data.